# Как посчитать количество строк в файле типа ASCII text, with CR line terminators?

Tags: shell, bash

Есть обычный `.txt` файл. Команда `file` показывается, что это `ASCII text, with CR line terminators`. Когда даю команду `wc -l example.txt` или `cat example.txt | wc -l` то получаю в результате `0`. Все потому что в конце строки стоит `CR`, а надо еще `LF`. Файл сам изменять не нужно. Пока остановился на варианте: `cat example.txt | sed -e 's/\r/\r\n/g' | sed -e "\$a\\" | wc -l`. Мне не нравится этот вариант тем что приходится добавлять строку (`sed -e "\$a\\"`) иначе `wc -l` показывает на строку меньше. Есть варианты получше?

Comment: Так не пойдёт?

    #include <stdio.h>
      int main() {
      int c=0, lcnt=0, flag=0, lastc;
      while((c = getchar()) != EOF) {
        flag = 1;
        lastc = c;
        if(c == '\r') lcnt++;
      }
      if(flag && lastc != '\r') lcnt++;
      printf("%d", lcnt);
      return 0;
    }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В Линуксе по умолчанию нужно только LF. Поэтому просто перекодируйте на лету CR -> LF и пропускайте через `wc`.

Попробуйте так:

```
tr '\r' '\n' example.txt | wc -l
```